# Java trying to check for anything multiplied by 60

Tags: java

I am coding a console game for the lulz and now im trying to check if the player is on the level 60, 120, 180, i.e. anything that is multiplied by 60.

Answer (score 4):

Check `level % 60 == 0` to see if the level is a multiple of 60. The `%` in Java is the [modulo operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operator).

Answer (score 2):

Check if the remainder is 0

```
if (level % 60 == 0) {..}
```

Comment: I only want like if the level is 60 or anything related to it, so i guess i would to like this then

Comment: well, this will be true if the level is 60,120,180, etc.

Comment: Wait, will this "if (level % 60 == 0)" only be true if the level is 60,120,180 etc or mine?

Comment: And if level == 0  ? and if level == - 60?

Comment: @Peter - yes, but I didn't mention those because of the context. Levels usually start at 1 and grow up.